# Is $\frac{\mathbb C[x,y]}{x^2+y^2+1}$ a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

UFD means every nonzero invertible elements has a unique factorization. Now I know that $\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle x^2+y^2-1 \rangle}$ is a UFD as it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}]$ but in $x^2+y^2+1=0$ we have $y^2+1=(y-i)(y+i)=(-x)(x)$ so the factorization is not unique. Can someone show that it is also isomorphic to $\mathbb C[e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}]$
Is my above logic true?

Comment: How is your isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/<x^2+y^2-1> \cong \mathbb{C}[e^{it},e^{-it}]$ is given? Your logic works same for the previous example, since $(y-1)(y+1)=(-x)x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/ (x^2 + y^2 + 1) \to \mathbb{C}[e^{it},e^{-it}]$ by mapping x to $e^{it}$ and y to $e^{-it}$ notice that $xy$ will be sent to $e^{it} \cdot e^{-it} = 1$ the image, but $xy$ is not 1 in R.

So something must have gone wrong in the construction of the isomorphism.